# How to keep checkboxes check on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

For this task, I have checkboxes attached to each post in an app, like so:
[image: Favoriting a post]

I have written code that will take the ID of that post and save it to a favorites array when the checkbox is checked, and remove it from the array when the checkbox is unchecked:

```
async saveFavStory(storyId) {
console.log(storyId);

this.favorites = [];
let checked = document.querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']:checked");
checked.forEach((storyId) => {
  this.favorites.push(storyId);
});
console.log(this);
};
```

Now what I want to do is have that memory of a checkbox being checked or unchecked saved in localStorage when the page refreshes. Any recommendations on how to do that would be appreciated!

If it helps, the end goal is for a user to be able to favorite posts, and all those posts will populate the page once a "favorites" tab in the navbar is clicked. I haven't gotten there yet but it is the first step I'm taking.

Edit: Here is my attempt at using getItem and setItem

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let isChecked = localStorage.getItem("checkedbox");
  // now set it
  $('#testbox').prop('checked', isChecked)
});

$('#testbox').on('click', function() {
  localStorage.setItem("checkedbox", $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Here is the dynamic HTML that contains the checkboxes:

```js
const hostName = story.getHostName();

  return $(`
      <li id="${story.storyId}">
      <input type="checkbox" id="testbox" value="${story.storyId}">
        <a href="${story.url}" target="a_blank" class="story-link">
          ${story.title}
        </a>
        <small class="story-hostname">(${hostName})</small>
        <small class="story-author">by ${story.author}</small>
        <small class="story-user">posted by ${story.username}</small>
      </li>
    `);
}
```

And here is my function that pushes the ID of checked posts into the favorites array:

```js
 async saveFavStory(storyId) {
    console.log(storyId);

    this.favorites = [];
    let checked = document.querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']:checked");
    checked.forEach((storyId) => {
      this.favorites.push(storyId);
    });
    console.log(this);
  };
```

Comment: Use `localStorage`

Comment: You could update a cookie each time a checkbox change is made. When the page is refreshed, read the cookie and check the checkboxes accordingly. If no cookie, then leave the checkboxes unchecked. You may need to remove that cookie once the page has been submitted.

Comment: Have you made an attempt at using `localStorage.setItem` and `localStorage.getItem` to store your values and to retrieve them again on page init? If so include it and placing your html/js in the snippet editor (the icon in the question box top that looks like `<>`) so we had a more easily reproducible example it makes it easier for folks to help you.

Comment: I've edited my post to give you all a better idea of what I'm working with

Answer (score 0):

Using localStorage, first I'm getting favorites from localStorage, if it doesn't exist, its being set to an empty array. The quotes around the empty array are intentional, they are there to create a string empty array so JSON.parse can work no matter if localstorage is empty or not.

Then I loop through the savedFavorites array and check any checkboxes with the appropriate ID.

In the createFavorites function, I'm now saving the data to a temporary variable called favorites. Then I overwrite the favorites localStorage with the new data.

Like in my original answer, I'm not messing with DELETING anything from local storage. I just rebuild it every time. Deleting/Updating will just get messy with additional if statements, functionality.

```
let stories = document.querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']");
let savedFavorites = localStorage.getItem("favorites") || "[]";
savedFavorites = JSON.parse(savedFavorites)

savedFavorites.forEach(function(id) {
  let check = document.querySelector("input[type='checkbox'][value='" + id + "']");
  if (check) {
    check.checked = true
  }
});

function createFavorites() {
  let favorites = [];
  let checked = document.querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']:checked");
  checked.forEach(function(el) {
    favorites.push(el.value);
  });
  localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favorites))
}

stories.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("change", function() {
    createFavorites();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! However, my saveFavStory function (your createFavorites function I believe) is defined under the class User. I'm fairly novice, but when I try to use your code, the "let stories, let savedFavorites", etc throws an unexpected token error. Do you have any recommendations on how I can implement this considering the methods for favoriting a post are in a class?